# PHP and HTML radio button errors

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I am totally new to PHP and recently learned how to program in PHP and knew a little about HTML already. I have been working on this code using radio buttons , POST forms and also inbuilt PHP functions incuding decbin,dechex etc. please check for errors im the code . I'm sure its one of my own mistakes but help will be respected.
INDEX.HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>Radio Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function validateForm() 
{
var x=document.forms["values"]["numeral"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert(":(");
return false;
}
}
</script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700'         rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sofia' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class = 'login'>
<h2>Number Converter</h2>
<form method="post" action="conversion.php" name='values'>
<input name='numeral' placeholder='A Number' type='text' autocomplete="off">
<input type="radio" name="rate" id="r1" value="Decimal to others" checked hidden>
<label for="r1" class="radio"><span></span>Decimal to Others</label>
<input type="radio" name="rate" id="r2" value="Binary to others" hidden>
<label for="r2" class="radio"><span></span>Binary to Others</label>
<input type="radio" name="rate" id="r3" value="HexaDecimal to others" hidden>
<label for="r3" class="radio"><span></span>HexaDecimal to others</label>
<input class='animated' type='submit' value='Convert' name='convert'> 
<a class='forgot' href='http://www.facebook.com/nalinbhardwaj.nib' target='_blank'>This project was created by Nalin Bhardwaj</a>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

heres conversion.php

CONVERSION.PHP

```
<?php

$a = $_POST["numeral"];
if (isset($_POST['convert'])) {

$selected_radio = $_POST['rate'];

if ($selected_radio == 'Decimal to Others') {

echo decbin($a);
echo dechex($a);

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have a space between ==?

Comment: Though that was a mistake, correcting it doesnt change anything

Comment: Do you get any error message on submitting the form?

Comment: semi colon missing after `$a = $_POST["numeral"]` is that also a typo?

Comment: No error message is being recieved, am getting a balnk screen

Comment: `Decimal to others` in HTML and `Decimal to Others` in PHP where `O` is lowercase in HTML and uppercase in PHP. When you equate them in PHP it doesn't get into the if condition which is way you get a blank screen

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in this section.

```
$a = $_POST["numeral"]  // semicolon missing
if ($selected_radio = = 'Decimal to Others') {   // unwanted space

echo decbin($a)     // semicolon missing
echo dechex($a)     // semicolon missing

}
```

Change this section to:

```
    $a = $_POST["numeral"];
   if (isset($_POST['convert'])) {
   $selected_radio = $_POST['rate'];
   if ($selected_radio == 'Decimal to Others') {
   echo decbin($a);
   echo dechex($a);
}
}
```

Comment: Line 4 is 'if (isset($_POST['convert'])) {'
 right??

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and ya they were wrong, but even now I am facing a blank screen with nothing in it. WHY SO ?

Comment: may be ur form doesn't get submitted..try to echo something before each lines in conversion.php and you will get to know in which line the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

i think in value check 'Decimal to Others' is 'Decimal to others' o is of smallcase in you radio value

```
 <?php

$a = $_POST["numeral"]
if (isset($_POST['convert'])) {

$selected_radio = $_POST['rate'];

if ($selected_radio == 'Decimal to Others') {

echo decbin($a);
echo dechex($a);

}
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, if u want to get radio button value to be submitted into another file try to add extra hidden data type along with radio button(because radio button value doesn't get submitted sometimes)

```
    <form method="post" action="conversion.php" name='values'>
    <input type="hidden" name="radio_value" id="radio_value" value="" />
     <input name='numeral' placeholder='A Number' type='text' autocomplete="off">
     <input type="radio" name="rate" id="r1" onClick="document.getElementById(radio_value).value='Decimal to others'" >
     <label for="r1" class="radio"><span></span>Decimal to Others</label>
     <input type="radio" name="rate" id="r2" onClick="document.getElementById(radio_value).value='Binary to others'" >         
     <label for="r2" class="radio"><span></span>Binary to Others</label>
     <input type="radio" name="rate" id="r3" onClick="document.getElementById(radio_value).value='HexaDecimal to others'" >         
     <label for="r3" class="radio"><span></span>HexaDecimal to others</label>
     <input class='animated' type='submit' value='Convert' name='convert'> 
     <a class='forgot' href='http://www.facebook.com/nalinbhardwaj.nib' target='_blank'>This project was created by Nalin Bhardwaj</a>
    </form>
```

And in Javascript change this

```
       $a = $_POST["numeral"];
     if (isset($_POST['convert'])) {
       $selected_radio = $_POST['radio_value'];
     if ($selected_radio == 'Decimal to others') {
       echo decbin($a);
       echo dechex($a);
      }
```